# What's the best way to use SOAP with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap

A client of mine has asked me to integrate a 3rd party API into their Rails app.  The only problem is that the API uses SOAP.  Ruby has basically dropped SOAP in favor of REST.  They provide a Java adapter that apparently works with the Java-Ruby bridge, but we'd like to keep it all in Ruby, if possible.  I looked into soap4r, but it seems to have a slightly bad reputation.

So what's the best way to integrate SOAP calls into a Rails app?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

We used the built in `soap/wsdlDriver` class, which is actually SOAP4R.
It's dog slow, but really simple. The SOAP4R that you get from gems/etc is just an updated version of the same thing.

Example code:

```
require 'soap/wsdlDriver'

client = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new( 'http://example.com/service.wsdl' ).create_rpc_driver
result = client.doStuff();
```

That's about it

Comment: Part of the reason why this is "Dog Slow" is that you are building the proxy every time you connect to the service. You could avoid this pain by using wsdl2ruby to build the proxy permanently and then call the pre-generated proxy.

Comment: We could, but that'd mean installing wsdl2ruby and so on and so forth. Sometimes Dog Slow is fine :-)

Comment: If you need to build proxy classes for Savon, you can follow [kredmer's](https://github.com/kredmer/memotoo/blob/master/lib/memotoo/main.rb) approach of building soap methods on-the-fly with the help of SoapUI to populate method names and not having to build a custom wsdl parser :). Instead of storing all methods in memory you can write to file, especially if you have tons.

Comment: 04/2015: Soap4r is dead, website is down. It seems Savon is the common choice at this moment.

Comment: I've been digging around in this space and discovered soap4r-ng, that's still being maintained https://github.com/rubyjedi/soap4r

Answer (score 170):

I built [Savon](http://savonrb.com) to make interacting with SOAP webservices via Ruby as easy as possible.
I'd recommend you check it out.

Comment: +1 for savon, not to bash soap4r - but I had really bad experience with it. Lack of good documentation and too cumbersome.

Comment: Nice! The SOAP world in ruby has improved since last time I had to use Soap4R to do this (~18 months ago)

Comment: can any one of you please help me to to hit sabre api using savon? I have a code that savon providing me  the methods using wsdl of the SOAP but I'm unable to send the request using savon in xml format.

Answer (score 13):

We switched from Handsoap to Savon.

Here is a [series of blog posts](http://www.dzone.com/links/savon_handsoap_shootout_two_popular_ruby_soap_cli.html) comparing the two client libraries.

Answer (score 5):

I also recommend [Savon](http://wiki.github.com/rubiii/savon). I spent too many hours trying to deal with Soap4R, without results. Big lack of functionality, no doc.

Savon is the answer for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try **SOAP4R**

- [SOAP4R](http://dev.ctor.org/soap4r)
- [Getting Started with SOAP4R](http://markthomas.org/2007/09/12/getting-started-with-soap4r/)

And I just heard about this on the Rails Envy Podcast (ep 31):

- [WS-Deathstar SOAP walkthrough](http://hideoustriumph.wordpress.com/2008/05/05/ws-deathstar-for-the-rest-of-us/)

Answer (score 3):

Just got my stuff working within 3 hours using Savon.

The Getting Started documentation on Savon's homepage was really easy to follow - and actually matched what I was seeing (not always the case)

Answer (score 2):

Kent Sibilev from [Datanoise](http://www.datanoise.com/) had also ported the Rails ActionWebService library to Rails 2.1 (and above).
This allows you to expose your own Ruby-based SOAP services.
He even has a scaffold/test mode which allows you to test your services using a browser.

Answer (score 2):

I have used HTTP call like below to call a SOAP method,

```
require 'net/http'

class MyHelper
  def initialize(server, port, username, password)
    @server = server
    @port = port
    @username = username
    @password = password

    puts "Initialised My Helper using #{@server}:#{@port} username=#{@username}"
  end



  def post_job(job_name)

    puts "Posting job #{job_name} to update order service"

    job_xml ="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns=\"http://test.com/Test/CreateUpdateOrders/1.0\">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
       <ns:CreateTestUpdateOrdersReq>
          <ContractGroup>ITE2</ContractGroup>
          <ProductID>topo</ProductID>
          <PublicationReference>#{job_name}</PublicationReference>
       </ns:CreateTestUpdateOrdersReq>
    </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>"

    @http = Net::HTTP.new(@server, @port)
    puts "server: " + @server  + "port  : " + @port
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(('/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?/Test/CreateUpdateOrders/1.0'), initheader = {'Content-Type' => 'text/xml'})
    request.basic_auth(@username, @password)
    request.body = job_xml
    response = @http.request(request)

    puts "request was made to server " + @server

    validate_response(response, "post_job_to_pega_updateorder job", '200')

  end



  private 

  def validate_response(response, operation, required_code)
    if response.code != required_code
      raise "#{operation} operation failed. Response was [#{response.inspect} #{response.to_hash.inspect} #{response.body}]"
    end
  end
end

/*
test = MyHelper.new("mysvr.test.test.com","8102","myusername","mypassword")
test.post_job("test_201601281419")
*/
```

Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thx for posting this. I just do it the same way! Keep it simple :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have used SOAP in Ruby when i've had to make a fake SOAP server for my acceptance tests. I don't know if this was the best way to approach the problem, but it worked for me.

I have used Sinatra gem (I wrote about creating mocking endpoints with Sinatra [here](http://intelligentbee.com/blog/2016/01/06/how-to-mock-endpoints-in-automated-acceptance-tests/)) for server and also [Nokogiri](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri/versions/1.6.7.2) for XML stuff (SOAP is working with XML).

So, for the beginning I have create two files (e.g. config.rb and responses.rb) in which I have put the predefined answers that SOAP server will return. 
In *config.rb* I have put the WSDL file, but as a string.

```
@@wsdl = '<wsdl:definitions name="StockQuote"
         targetNamespace="http://example.com/stockquote.wsdl"
         xmlns:tns="http://example.com/stockquote.wsdl"
         xmlns:xsd1="http://example.com/stockquote.xsd"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
         xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
         .......
      </wsdl:definitions>'
```

In *responses.rb* I have put samples for responses that SOAP server will return for different scenarios.

```
@@login_failure = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <LoginResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <LoginResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WEBMethodsObjects" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:Error>Invalid username and password</a:Error>
                <a:ObjectInformation i:nil="true"/>
                <a:Response>false</a:Response>
            </LoginResult>
        </LoginResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>"
```

So now let me show you how I have actually created the server.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require 'nokogiri'
require_relative 'config/config.rb'
require_relative 'config/responses.rb'

after do
# cors
headers({
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" => "POST",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" => "content-type",
})

# json
content_type :json
end

#when accessing the /HaWebMethods route the server will return either the WSDL file, either and XSD (I don't know exactly how to explain this but it is a WSDL dependency)
get "/HAWebMethods/" do
  case request.query_string
    when 'xsd=xsd0'
        status 200
        body = @@xsd0
    when 'wsdl'
        status 200
        body = @@wsdl
  end
end

post '/HAWebMethods/soap' do
request_payload = request.body.read
request_payload = Nokogiri::XML request_payload
request_payload.remove_namespaces!

if request_payload.css('Body').text != ''
    if request_payload.css('Login').text != ''
        if request_payload.css('email').text == some username && request_payload.css('password').text == some password
            status 200
            body = @@login_success
        else
            status 200
            body = @@login_failure
        end
    end
end
end
```

I hope you'll find this helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, switched to Savon and then just tested it on an open WSDL (I used http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL) and so far so good!

https://github.com/savonrb/savon