# SOAP JAX-WS client in Ruby

Tags: ruby, soap, jax-ws

I want to write a ruby web service client for a SOAP (JAX-WS) web service. I looked into soap4r and handsoap but couldn't find useful resources to write a (JAX-WS) client

Can you help me to find some resources and some way of doing it. Because as I can see, my web service is developed using oracle JDeveloper and looks little different than examples find in web.

I'm a beginner for SOAP, WSDL web services and finding it hard.

Has anyone done something like this before, or can you turn me to the correct direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAX-WS is an API for the development of web services in Java.  Know then that, in order to consume a SOAP/WSDL based web service, it is not necessary to know how that web service was implemented.  It could be Java, .NET or any other number of languages.  All that is required to create a SOAP based web service client is the WSDL for the service.  It is self contained and self descriptive, including all operations and data types supported by the web service.

In order to familiarize yourself with web services, I would recommend trying to exercise some web services directly, for example using [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/).  This will allow you to import a WSDL for an active web service, try out some of the operations, and see what the corresponding SOAP messages look like.  Then, I would look at ["What's the best way to use soap with ruby?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273/whats-the-best-way-to-use-soap-with-ruby) for more ruby specific approaches.