# SOAP in Rails3?

Tags: soap, ruby-on-rails-3

How to use SOAP web service in Rails3?
I tried datanoise-actionwebservice but doesn't work for me. I heard that rails3 has integrated SOAP support, but I don't find nothing about this on the internet. Can you help me?

Comment: REST is pretty much what all rails developers use. Do a little more searching. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273/whats-the-best-way-to-use-soap-with-ruby

Comment: I think/hope the question is how do you consume a SOAP API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're using [Savon](http://savon.rubiii.com/) with Rails 3, works well for our use (Google Adwords API)

Comment: Can I make with Savon my own web service and use them from another app?

Comment: for that you're best bet is http://github.com/rubyjedi/actionwebservice not rails 3 though

Comment: I am trying to use Savon with the Google Adwords API and running into SSL errors.  Did you have to do anything special to get Savon working with SSL?

Comment: just use the https url for the endpoint. You do need to get the auth token and make sure you turn on ssl for that:


      http_client = Net::HTTP.new(hostname, port);
      http_client.use_ssl = true