# Ruby on Rails - WebService - ASMX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, asmx, webservice-client

my question how can I call (to make the connection and invoke a method) of a webservice asmx?
Thanks.

Tiago T.

Answer (score 0):

ASMX generally use SOAP. Not always, but generally. I used google -- here are some resources:

- [What's the best way to use SOAP with Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273/whats-the-best-way-to-use-soap-with-ruby)
- http://rpheath.com/posts/298-consuming-soap-services-in-ruby