# Using Web Services on SharePoint with Ruby Controllers

Tags: ruby, web-services, sharepoint

I'm completely new to Ruby and Web Services.

I want to tap into SharePoint and retrieve specific data files using available Web Services. Most of the available documentation on the web seems to involve VB IDEs. Can someone please show me how Web Services can be used with ROR controllers? Any beginner examples/literature would be of great help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is straight forward SOAP call since sharepoint exposed as a SOAP web service. You can use SOAP4R to achieve this

Refer the links for more info

1. [consuming-soap-services-in-ruby](http://rpheath.com/posts/298-consuming-soap-services-in-ruby)
2. [whats-the-best-way-to-use-soap-with-ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273/whats-the-best-way-to-use-soap-with-ruby)