# Sabre Dev Studio API call by ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, sabre, sabredav

I'm trying to take hotels details  from sabre dev studio in my app and I'm using `gem 'sabre_dev_studio'` but I can't understand how and which url I have to hit (APIs) for the hotel details. I'm using like this :

```
SabreDevStudio.configure do |c|
    c.client_id     = 'V1:kiifsurie29jj:KITPUI:DFR'
    c.client_secret = 'wiurRTs'
    c.uri           = 'https://api.test.sabre.com'
  end
  token = SabreDevStudio::Base.get_access_token
  themes = SabreDevStudio::Base.get('/v1/shop/themes')
```

this is working and give me proper response but for hotels I'm not getting which url are for apies.

Comment: Just a side comment, I would not publish your creds on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_basics/endpoints_and_uris

This is the list of the urls you'll want

Comment: Thanks @ABrowne but there are not any api for Hotels here. I'm looking for hotels.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no REST APIs for hotels, only SOAP at the moment.
Here's the related documentation:
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/hotel

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm unable to hit the SOAP API if you have any idea please share with me. I'm using code as I have mention at the question using gem 'sabre_dev_studio' gem

Comment: The Ruby sample is for REST only APIs.
In order to hit SOAP APIs, you will require to get a session token first (submitting your SOAP credentials that you will need to get from Sabre)
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_basics/Authentication

And then use that token in a subsequent SOAP service call.

You can get test SOAP credentials contacting Sabre using this form:
https://developer.sabre.com/contact

Comment: I'hv seen the basic authentication process there is some xml request and I'm not understand how do I make request for this authentication please help me if you have any idea in coding steps for ruby.

Comment: Does this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273/whats-the-best-way-to-use-soap-with-ruby

Comment: can you please help to to hit sabre api using savon? I have a code that savon providing me  the methods using wsdl of the SOAP but I'm unable to send the request using savon in xml format.